# How to skip validation when a specific button is clicked?

Tags: validation, jsf, button, jsf-2

I have a form with a validator on one field. I have two `h:commandButton`s: *Ok* and *Cancel*. When I input wrong data and click *Cancel*, I get a validation message. What must I do that validator don't run when I click *cancel*?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

In case you aren't using ajax, or are still on JSF 1.x, and you really need to invoke a business action in `cancel()` method (i.e. just reloading the page is insufficient), then your best bet is to add `immediate="true"` to the button. This way all input fields which don't have `immediate="true"` will be skipped in processing.

```
<h:commandButton value="Cancel" action="#{bean.cancel}" immediate="true" />
```

On JSF 2.x, much better is to submit the form by `<f:ajax>`, which by default only processes `@this` instead of `@form`.

```
<h:commandButton value="Cancel" action="#{bean.cancel}">
    <f:ajax />
</h:commandButton>
```

If you want to navigate to another page here, add `?faces-redirect=true` to the outcome in the `cancel()` method.

Or, if you actually don't need to invoke any business action at all, then just use `<h:button>` wherein you directly specify the (implicit) navigation case outcome.

```
<h:button value="Cancel" outcome="previouspage" />
```

This will basically reload the page by a GET request. The `<h:button>` doesn't exist in JSF 1.x, but you can also just use plain HTML+JS for that.

#### See also:

- [Why was "immediate" attribute added to the EditableValueHolders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13071512/why-was-immediate-property-added-to-the-editablevalueholders/)
- [How to navigate in JSF? How to make URL reflect current page (and not previous one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521451/how-to-navigate-in-jsf-how-to-make-url-reflect-current-page-and-not-previous-o)
- [How to let validation depend on the pressed button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370675/how-to-let-validation-depend-on-the-pressed-button)

Comment: Follow-up: How can it be done if I have e.g. `<h:selectOneMenu` with `onchange="submit()"`? How can validation be skipped if a new selection in the dropdown triggers a post back to the server? (I have to stick to jsf 1.1, sigh...)

Comment: @BalusC Do you know a way to skip the validation phase but process the update model values phase? Is this possible in JSF 2?

Comment: @SurprisedCoconut Yes,this can be possible in JSF 2 by removing validators Only for the PROCESS_VALIDATIONS phase in your PhaseListener Class