# p:commandButton doesn't call action on validation error

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces, cancel-button

So i have this cancel button:

```
<p:commandButton id="cancelButton" value="Cancel" action="#{myBean.doOnCancel}" onclick="dialogWidget.hide();" />
```

The widget which the cancel button is on (`<p:dialog>`) has a date field. Everytime i open the dialog, enter some valid values and click cancel - `myBean.doOnCancel` gets executed and the dialog is hidden. 
Now everytime i open the dialog, enter a single invalid value, such as a single letter instead of date, i get a validation message saying the date format is bad, then click cancel - the dialog is hidden but the method defined in action (`myBean.doOnCancel`) is not executed.
Any idea why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JSF will as per specification not invoke the action method when there's a validation error during processing the form submit. The `<p:commandButton>` processes by default the entire form as in `<p:commandButton process="@form">`. You want to limit it to the button itself only.

```
<p:commandButton ... process="@this" />
```

The dialog got successfully hidden, because it was performed entirely client side right before the form is submitted, independently from the result of the action method.

#### See also:

- [Understanding PrimeFaces process/update and JSF f:ajax execute/render attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-process-and-update-attributes-of-primefaces/)
- [How to skip validation when a specific button is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062923/how-to-skip-validation-when-a-specific-button-is-clicked)